# javascript anonymous function call with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Can someone explain the parameter `e` in the anonymous function call. I am unable to understand how can the anonymous function accept the parameter (the second line in the below code). This code is taken from `DropZone`.

```
 updateProgress = (function(_this) {
    return function(e) {
      var allFilesFinished, progress, _j, _k, _l, _len1, _len2, _len3, _results;
      if (e != null) {
        progress = 100 * e.loaded / e.total;
        for (_j = 0, _len1 = files.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
          file = files[_j];
          file.upload = {
            progress: progress,
            total: e.total,
            bytesSent: e.loaded
          };
        }
      } else {
        allFilesFinished = true;
        progress = 100;
        for (_k = 0, _len2 = files.length; _k < _len2; _k++) {
          file = files[_k];
          if (!(file.upload.progress === 100 && file.upload.bytesSent === file.upload.total)) {
            allFilesFinished = false;
          }
          file.upload.progress = progress;
          file.upload.bytesSent = file.upload.total;
        }
        if (allFilesFinished) {
          return;
        }
      }
      _results = [];
      for (_l = 0, _len3 = files.length; _l < _len3; _l++) {
        file = files[_l];
        _results.push(_this.emit("uploadprogress", file, progress, file.upload.bytesSent));
      }
      return _results;
    };
  })(this);
```

this is how it is assigned to the onprogress

```
 progressObj = (_ref = xhr.upload) != null ? _ref : xhr;
  progressObj.onprogress = updateProgress;
```

then it is called as

```
    updateProgress();
```

Comment: Yes I know `this` is coming in the end... but how does this gets passed to the function .. and how does it know??

Comment: That has nothing to do with `this`.

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying.. it has nothing to do with this .. so who is calling this function or say who can call it.. its return statement.. :o

Comment: Whoever gets `updateProgress` passed can call the function. We don't know what `e` will be because you don't show what happens to `updateProgress`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever **calls** `updateProgress` will pass an argument, which then can be referenced via `e`.

Example:

`updateProgress(42)`: `e` would now refer to `42`.

Most likely `updateProgress` will be used as event handler, so `e` would refer to the event object.

Comment: did you check the code properly.. 
The function is called on the end with `this` as parameter. but how does the anonymous function in the return knows about that definition??

Comment: *"The function is called on the end with this as parameter."* Yes, but that is irrelevant. The function returns another  function (`return function(e) { ... }`), and that is the value assigned to `updateProgress`. `updateProgress` is the function that defines `e` as argument. What did you think `return function() { ... };` does?

Comment: I am confused .. so why is the `this` is passed?

Comment: Most likely just to  be able to reference it inside the inner function via `_this`. Again, what you are asking for has nothing to do with `this` or the outer function call. The whole code is equivalent to `var updateProgress = function(e) { ... };`. Is that clearer now? `e` is set by the code that *calls* `updateProgress` (somehow, you are not showing what is done with `updateProgress`).

Comment: So something (not you) will call `progressObj.onprogress(event)` at some point. `e` will point to `event` then. Don't think too complicated: `updateProgress` is a function. Whatever calls it will pass an argument to it. That argument can be referred to by `e`. Function 101: `function foo(e) { alert(e); }; foo(42)` will alert 42.

Comment: Maybe this is not clear yet: `return function(e) { ... }` does **not** call the function. It simply creates the function and returns it.

Comment: Thank you sooooo veryyyyy much... Great!

Comment: please update the answer and include the bits in the comments.. so someone else can get help.

Answer (score 2):

The function expressions are just used to create scope. The function that is returned from the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) is assigned to the `updateProgress` varible, so the final result is basically as if you had a regular function with a parameter:

```
function updateProgress(e) {
  var allFilesFinished, ...
  ...
  return _results;
}
```

When `updateProgress` is used as an event handler, it will be called with the event object as the first parameter. That ends up in the `e` parameter.

When called without a value, the parameter `e` gets the value `undefined`. That makes the code execute the `else` part, i.e. showing the progress at 100%.

Comment: so it means `this` is assigned to it as parameter?

Comment: @whatever: No, the `this` that is sent into the IIFE ends up in the `_this` parameter, that is later used in the function. It's similar to using the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context for a function.